# How to stop Redux RTK query from retrying on error

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I have some requests which may return 404s. When they do, RTK query will send retries, resulting in hundreds of failed requests. Why is it trying to refetch on error and what can I do?

Answer (score 5):

If your endpoint is in error, RTK Query's `useQuery` will send a request in two situations:

- you change the argument (that would always result in a new request)
- you mount a component using this `useQuery`.

So without seeing your code, I would assume that your component re-mounts somehow and thus leads to another request after mounting.

Comment: in my case it was ```maxRetries:0``` not working as expected, which is solved in ```v1.9.1```

Answer (score 3):

you can limit the number of retries that rtk automatically does by using the property `maxRetries` inside your end point.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery, retry } from 
'@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

// maxRetries: 5 is the default, and can be omitted. Shown for 
documentation purposes.
const staggeredBaseQuery = retry(fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }), {
  maxRetries: 5,
})
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: staggeredBaseQuery,
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getPosts: build.query({
      query: () => ({ url: 'posts' }),
    }),
    getPost: build.query({
      query: (id) => ({ url: `post/${id}` }),
     extraOptions: { maxRetries: 5 }, // You can override the retry behavior on each endpoint
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useGetPostsQuery, useGetPostQuery } = api
```

Answer (score 0):

As [docs say](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-queries-with-queryfn), for custom error handling we can use `queryFn`:

> One-off queries that use different error handling behaviour

So if, for any reason, you want to cache request on error, you can do:

```
getPokemon: build.query<Pokemon, string>({
  async queryFn(name, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) {
    const result = await baseQuery({
      url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`,
      method: 'GET'
    });

    if (result.error?.status === 404) {
      // don't refetch on 404
      return { data: result.data as Pokemon };
    }

    if (result.error) {
      // but refetch on another error
      return { error: result.error };
    }

    return { data: result.data as Pokemon };
  }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your createApi function. you can stop permanently retries with setting **unstable__sideEffectsInRender** property to false

```
import {
  buildCreateApi,
  coreModule,
  reactHooksModule,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react';

const createApi = buildCreateApi(
  coreModule(),
  reactHooksModule({ unstable__sideEffectsInRender: false })
);

export default createApi;
```

Answer (score 0):

const {isError} = useQuery();

if (isError)
show error message
else
render the components.

check the isError property return by useQuery before the component renders. If API failed then 'isError' becomes true then renders the components, which will prevent multiple API requests for the failed scenario.